# Combining resultset to get one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a query of tables which returns output as

```
AccessRightID   NodeID  NodeName    CanAdd  CanEdit CanDelete   CanView
1                  2    Customer       0       0        0          1
2                  2    Customer       1       1        0          0
3                  2    Customer       0       0        0          0
4                  2    Customer       0       0        0          0
```

now i want to combine and get only one row.AccessRightId is not needed.
the final output should be like.

```
NodeID  NodeName    CanAdd  CanEdit CanDelete   CanView
2       Customer        1        1        0         1
```

i.e if any value contains 1 then 1 else 0.

plz suggest as i m new to sql.

Comment: CANNOT USE SUM AS IT IS BIT COLUMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
NodeId
,NodeName
,max(convert(int,CanAdd))
,max(convert(int,CanDelete))
,max(convert(int,CanEdit))
,max(convert(int,CanView))
from yourtable
group by
NodeId, NodeName
```

For sure it can be done other way but this one sounds easiest.

Comment: it was so easy casted to int thnks.

Comment: is there any ways to handle this